# gyp and precompiled headers for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers, gyp

Is **gyp** capable of generating precompiled header options for C++ project for MS Visual Studio?

There was a doc called [WindowsPrecompiledHeaders](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjABahUKEwi__MCcsuzHAhUGjnIKHUOzC4w&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fchromium%2Fwiki%2FWindowsPrecompiledHeaders&usg=AFQjCNEN6JWdUN-xTBAcGtQ0_S-w5y3IeQ&sig2=585OSLYFj6CMW6JlXgs1Hw), but it is 404 there now. Current gyp documentation contains no information about it.

Google web cache does not contain it, too.

Is there any docs about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was simple:

```
'msvs_precompiled_header': 'stdafx.h',
'msvs_precompiled_source': 'stdafx.cpp',
```

in `.gyp` file for given target.